# setChecked() not working in class

Tags: c++, qt

I was making a small test program in Qt 5, and tried implementing a check box class with the default being the box is checked. However, whenever I run the program, it seems that the checkbox is not checked. Here is the following code:

checkbox.h:

```
    #ifndef CHECKBOX
    #define CHECKBOX

    #include <QCheckBox>
    #include <QWidget>



   class checkbox : public QCheckBox
   {
   public:

        checkbox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QCheckBox(parent)
        {
            QCheckBox *cBox = new QCheckBox;
           cBox->setChecked(true);
        }
    };

    #endif // CHECKBOX
```

main.cpp:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QAction>
    #include <QtWidgets>
    #include <checkbox.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QWidget *window = new QWidget;

        window->setWindowTitle("test");
        checkbox *box = new checkbox;

        QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        mainLayout->addWidget(box);

       window->setLayout(mainLayout);
       window->show();

       return a.exec();
    }
```

Funny thing is though, if I call setChecked with box in main, it ouputs a checked box.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing this...

```
QCheckBox *cBox = new QCheckBox;
cBox->setChecked(true);
```

...which creates a second dynamically allocated `QCheckBox` - distinct from the base object embedded in your `checkbox` - then leaks that object/memory.  You should simply check the embedded base class `QCheckBox` by calling the inherited member function:

```
checkbox(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
  : QCheckBox(parent)
{
    setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: but if cbox is a child of checkbox, shouldn't it be destroyed when it's parent is destroyed?

Comment: understood, forgot that -> simply creates a copy, thanks!

Comment: "child" is not terminology used in C++.  There are two things similar to your notion - if `cBox` were a member variable of `checkbox` then any destructor for it would be run, then the memory released, when `checkbox`'s destructor runs. But a raw pointer doesn't have a meaningful destructor - it doesn't `delete` the pointed-to `QCheckBox`, so you'd still have a leak.  People use smart pointers to automate such cleanup: `std::unique_ptr cBox;`.  Similarly, there are "automatic" variables that are cleaned up when the function or `if`/`while`/`for` etc. scope in which they're created exits.

Comment: ok, I see. thanks for clearing that one up for me, and sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: @Manny: you're welcome - and no need to apologise - everyone has to start somewhere.  Might be easier for you with a good book though (there's an existing recommended reading list for C++ on S.O. somewhere, but I don't have a link nor my own recommendations for beginners).  Cheers.